# Qt Hide Taskbar Item

Tags: qt, taskbar, qwidget

I have a custom QWidget and I simple don't want it to show up in the taskbar. I have a QSystemTrayIcon for managing exiting/minimizing etc.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I think the only thing you need here is some sort of parent placeholder widget. If you create your widget without a parent it is considered a top level window. But if you create it as a child of a top level window it is considered a child window und doesn't get a taskbar entry per se. The parent window, on the other hand, also doesn't get a taskbar entry because you never set it visible: This code here works for me:

```
class MyWindowWidget : public QWidget
{
public:
    MyWindowWidget(QWidget *parent)
        : QWidget(parent, Qt::Dialog)
    {

    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QMainWindow window;

    MyWindowWidget widget(&window);
    widget.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

No taskbar entry is ever shown, if this is want you intended.

Comment: I was facing this with one of App and after reading I realised problem was someone commit a object creation with this object. It was bug for me. I removed `this` and app worked perfectly i.e. taskbar entry comes back. Thanks you.

Answer (score 15):

Just set Qt::SubWindow flag for widget.

Comment: This is definitely the easiest answer. Works for me with Qt5.

Comment: It's a good solution if Your window has no frame. If it does, then you wont have the default windows buttons (close, maximize, minimize).

Comment: Where do I put this code? Can you give more detailed example?

Answer (score 10):

If you want to show/hide the widget without ever showing it at the taskbar your might check the windowflags of that widget. I'm not 100% sure, but I think I used `Qt::Dialog` | `Qt::Tool` and `Qt::CustomizeWindowHint` to achieve this, but my window wasn't fully decorated too. Another thing you might keep in mind if you play with that is the exit policy of your application. Closing/Hiding the last toplevel-window will normally exit your application, so maybe you need to call `QApplication::setQuitOnLastWindowClosed(false)` to prevent that...

Comment: `Qt::Tool` is the relevant flag that prevents a taskbar entry.

Comment: Nvm got it: this->setWindowFlags(Qt::tool);

Comment: Heads up: On some WMs even children with parents are listed in the taskbar. As mentioned elsewhere setting the window type to Qt::Tool solves this but then some WMs don't allow maximizing of Tool windows. If you need that too you have to send the "_NET_WM_STATE_SKIP_TASKBAR" manually by getting the X11 connection from X11Info

Comment: @SleepProgger : I was able to solve (or rather workaround) a similar problem thanks to your comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75584018/7410886

Answer (score 0):

Python code to achive this:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent, Qt.Tool)

window = MainWindow()
window.show()
```