# make a borderless app without a controlbox on Qt

Tags: qt

Is it possible to make a borderless window on Qt? I know its possible in Visual Studio you just change the value in the properties window. Qt doesnt have a formborderstyle property.

Also is it possible not to display icon on taskbar

Comment: If you use old versions of Qt (4.8.5 or 5.2) - be aware with next issue - https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-17548

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not possible to suppress the taksbar entry. Each top level window without a parent will get one.

It surely is possible to create a frameless window. I once used a plain QWidget for a similar purpose and add something like the following:

```
setWindowFlags(Qt::Dialog|Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting the window flags using setWindowFlags() on your top level widget with

- Qt::FramelessWindowHint - Draw without window frame

See the full doco at http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qt.html#WindowType-enum and http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#windowFlags-prop

As for hiding the taskbar look at this stack overflow example [Qt Hide Taskbar Item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4055506/qt-hide-taskbar-item) (just sets the windowFlags to include Qt::Dialog you could do what your looking for with

```
MyWindowWidget(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent, Qt::Dialog|Qt::FramelessWindowHint)
```