# How to hide application on taskbar?

Tags: c++, linux, qt

I am trying to hide my QT application from taskbar? I cannot find anything in Google so I asking here.
Solution from Qt Hide Taskbar Item ([Qt Hide Taskbar Item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4055506/qt-hide-taskbar-item)) and *this->hide()* is not helping.

main.cpp

```
#include "status_bar.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    status_bar w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

status_bar.cpp:

```
    #include "status_bar.h"
    #include "ui_status_bar.h"
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <QTime>
    #include <QTimer>
    #include <QApplication>
    #include <QDesktopWidget>

    status_bar::status_bar(QWidget *parent) :
        QMainWindow(parent),
        ui(new Ui::status_bar)
    {
        ui->setupUi(this);
        setWindowFlags(Qt::Window | Qt::FramelessWindowHint | Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint);
        resize(QApplication::desktop()->width(),36);
        ui->time->move(QApplication::desktop()->width()-ui->time->size().width(),10);
        ui->username->setText(getenv("USER"));
        timeupdate = new QTimer(this);
        connect(timeupdate, SIGNAL(timeout()),
                  this, SLOT(UpdateClock()));
        timeupdate->start(100);
    }

    void status_bar::UpdateClock()
    {
        ui->time->setText(QTime::currentTime().toString("HH:mm"));
    }

    status_bar::~status_bar()
    {
        delete ui;
    }
```

EDIT:
With code like this window is empty.

```
class MyWindowWidget : public QWidget
{
public:
    MyWindowWidget(QWidget *parent)
        : QWidget(parent, Qt::Dialog)
    {

    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    status_bar window;

    MyWindowWidget widget(&window);
    widget.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

Solved by using Qt::Tool flag.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Qt Hide Taskbar Item](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4055506/qt-hide-taskbar-item)

Comment: But solution from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4055506/qt-hide-taskbar-item is not helping.

Comment: what part of it is not helping?

Comment: `class MyWindowWidget : public QWidget
{
public:
    MyWindowWidget(QWidget *parent)
        : QWidget(parent, Qt::Dialog)
    {

    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QMainWindow window;

    MyWindowWidget widget(&window);
    widget.show();

    return app.exec();
}` modified to work with my class name.

Comment: You aren't following the code/instructions from the answer.  You need to make `QMainWindow` in main and pass it to the status bar constructor to make status bar a child window.

Comment: Also, with solution from stackoverflow.com/questions/4055506/qt-hide-taskbar-item there is no any widgets. Only background.

Answer (score -1):

Qt::Tool flag has other problems for me, like this widget/windows is hidden when its state becomes inactive.
I would recommend you to use Qt::ToolTip